Continuous infinitve with modal verbs
Before I ask another question I want to clarify that  I have been to  the USA, UK and even New Zealand I speak English well but still for example in my native language  these two forms " I was doing something and I did something" are pretty much interchangeable. In English it is different I know more or less when to use either infinitve or continuous infinitve but still when it comes to some structures I'm in doubt and that's why I'm asking this questin.
Let me provide examples
1 "When I was a kid I could/might/would/used to swim or I could/might/would/used to be swimming"
As far as I know continuous infinitve here wouldn't be right "swimming" was repeated many times and "when I was a kid" is a very long period not something short lasting or temoprary. Although, I see one reason why I would be eager to use continuous infinitve. This reason is to show and emphasize duration. So, could I use all those verbs which I enumerated, in  sentence number 2 and if not why?
2 "When I was a kid I used to/might/would/could be swimming for hours"
Ps. Note I used "for hours" to justify my choice of continuous infintive

When I was a kid, I would go swimming for hours.

@WeatherVane. I know I can say something like that, but my question is about something different. Still, thanks.

When I was a kid, I went swimming for hours. When I was a kid, I used to swim for hours. Can you clarify exactly what you are asking please?

I don't think "continuous infinitive" is relevant unless you say something like "I always wanted to be swimming".

Please use less vacuous examples.  Whether or not a particular form is idiomatic depends on  everything in the sentence that establishes (or reveals) context. A barebones "I didn't spend much time making this sentence" is not worth spending much time on.

@WeatherVane. I'm asking if it is fine to use continuos infintive instead of just continuous in this example "When I was a kid I used to/might/would/could be swimming for hours"

You do not grasp how "used to" is used.

So, explain please

Ask a separate question about "used to".  It would be more focused.

Ok but before answer my question please. Ok, "used to" is different but still we have "could, would and might"

Based on your introduction to your latest question, I would repeat the advice you've already been given. Don't try to make up your own random examples. There will always be possible sentences where your example could be correct, so you will remain stuck at your current level. Instead, get a book from the library. Read it. Come back to us with specific sentences that don't make sense to you. You will learn more that way.

Modals could, would, might can be used with "be" + the continuous form of a verb referring to ongoing past actions.

Back in the days before TV, the entire family could | would | might be sitting around the radio for hours  in the evening.
When I was a kid, on any given Saturday I could | would | might be mowing lawns to earn extra money.

But sometimes it will sound "off" to native speakers, who could|would|might want to hear the bare form of the infinitive:

Before the discovery of modern antiobiotics, doctors could | would | might be using use moldy bread to help heal wounds.

And why is that?  Because a frequent or regular activity, side-hustle, or past-time is not the same thing as standard operating procedure.

I even think that according to strict grammar rules which quite often aren't taken that seriously even your example "When I was a kid, on any given Saturday I could | would | might be mowing lawns to earn extra money" unncessary uses be plus the continuous form. Would you agree?

I think you're approaching the question in a very odd way to reject the continuous on the grounds of it not being "necessary".  Language is expressive.  The continuous expresses the fact a little differently than the bare form does: one might say it makes the actiivity referred to more "real" and less abstract by emphasizing its durative aspect. It's how the kid spent his Saturdays, how the family spent their evenings.

You say that language is expressive. But once I asked natives about this sentence " When I was a kid I was going to  school". They all stated that is sounds wrong. How then  can I know when this continuous form may be fine and when not?

The same way you know that a mushroom is poisonous.   Trial and error.

What do you mean?  You're a native. You feel it. I just don't. That's why I use some rules which help me to sound at least quite natural.

I will say it one more time. Your example sentences are vacuous. Lacking content.  They need to be more "fleshed out".  I can generate a natural-sounding sentence using "would be going to school" but in a barebones sentence like that, it sounds very unnatural.

When I was kid, the schoolhouse was three miles away and there were no roads like there are today. It was farm connected to farm connected to farm, with little lanes for horses and buggies. And not only was it rather far for a six-year-old to walk day in  and day out, we would be going to school on foot in all kinds of weather: rain, sleet, snow, high winds, hot sun. You name it. Why? Because school was better than farmwork any day of the week.

" When I was small I was going to school" meaning all my childchood every week for 5 days I went there. I don't mean something like "When I was little I was going to school  and out of the blue I saw a car". I mean repeates actions happening during all that time when I was a kid. Then, I thinl continuous isn't the best option and I appplied the same logic to yours "³bWhen I was a kid, on any given Saturday I could | would | might be mowing lawns to earn extra money." And stated that the continuous form isn't the best option here

Or "we were going to school in all kinds of weather..."

You need a context to justify the continous form. No more barebones sentences. Enough. I'm done with them.   These forms are compatible with and contribute to a context. They do not establish a context.

I don't do chat.  Please re-read my comment about context.

All my teachers forced me to believe that when an action is repeated and takes a lot of time for instance  if I wrote on a test somethinv like "Last Year I was driving a truck because it was my job" I would get zero poitns and they would insist on using past simple "I drove" because "last year" is a very long period of time and driving was repeated many times. What do you think about this approach?

Btw I asked another question about "used to".

"last year I was driving a truck" expresses the fact as an activity you were engaged in doing, whereas "drove a truck" expresses the fact as a gig or job. Both are natural and idiomatic.  You might use the job version in any context where you are telling someone what your job was during that period;  and you might use the continuous version in an informal conversation where you are emphasizing the nature of the activity itself, perhaps to say you spent many hours on the road, fighting highway hynosis or boredom, whatever.
