What's wrong with past continuous
I'd like to ask a question about the past continuous. I was taught to use it when:

two or more actions happen at the same time

-to emphasize length or show that something annoys us with expressions like "always, all the time"
-for temoprary events
-for background events
-to show that an action is interrupted by another one.
Now, my intention is to say what I did as an adult. What was my daily let's say routine.
A) As an adult, I was working
B) As an adult, I worked
I provided in points all situations when we can use continuous. None applies here, but still I meet people who claim that A is valid. Do you agree and why? Maybe A is a colloquial use of past continuous?

No, your example A isn't "colloquial". It's just non-idiomatic. But I don't understand why your past tense examples start with "As an adult". Presumably the speaker is still an adult, so why have you used past tense? Perhaps it would make more sense to compare As a child I went to school (natural) with As a child I was going to school (non-idiomatic as a stand-alone sentence, in the same way as your example A). Whatever - if you meet people who claim that A is valid, they obviously don't know what they're talking about.

@FumbleFingers. "As an adult" meaning actively working. I think someone who reitred could say that. Whatever, I didin't even thought about it.

A native speaker. He's a user of this site and certainly he knows a lot about English aprroved these two examples. 1When I was a kid, on any given Saturday I could | would | might be mowing lawns to earn extra money. 2 Last year I was driving a truck- intened meaning was to say whay was my job. How are they different. Here, I also see no reason for using continuous

I'm going to keep downvoting your questions for as long as you keep providing these vacuous (I.e. totally lacking context) example sentences. Many of your example sentences sound off to people because they're pretty much empty of the sort of thing that would justify the form you're asking about. "Before I retired, I was working long hours at two jobs."

Those are my example sentences that OP is questioning, BTW. And OP has not correctly reported what I said.

You have missed out For ongoing events from your list.

Here's the former question:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/352974/continuous-infinitve-with-modal-verbs

@KateBunting. "For ongoing events" what do you mean by that? " As an adult I was working long hours". It seems to be ongoing yet FumbleFingers says it's not idiomatic

I mean an action that continued for some time, of course - that's the main purpose of the continuous tense! It's not idiomatic to speak of being an adult in the past tense, since once you become one you are adult for the rest of your life. You could say "When I was in my twenties I was working long hours".

@KateBunting. 1 When I was a kid I was traveling a lot. 2 Last year I was swimming in the ocean. 3 when I retired I was sleeping. What about those? To me all of them are ongoing, therfore correct?

I’m voting to close this question because it asserts that a competent native Anglophone claims As an adult, I was working is a valid standalone utterance. But apparently, that "competent native Anglophone" says he's being misquoted. In the absence of (preferably, multiple) examples of a questionable usage with links, I don't see a valid question here.

@FumbleFingers. Please explain one thing to me and I will close this question on my own. Kate says continuous is used for "something ongoing"."When I was a kid I was going to school every day." So, why does it sound off since it was something ongoing?

Present Simple is often for ROUTINES 1. I wake up at 7 AM. 2. I get dressed. 3. I have my breakfast. 4. I take the bus to school 5. Mum tidies the house. 6. Dad cleans the car. 7. Mum takes the dog for a walk. 8. Dad makes dinner.  Present Continuous 3. I usually have coffee for breakfast but today I'm having green tea. Past Continuous (two events at the same time): 5. While Mum was tidying, Dad was cleaning the car. (or)  7. Dad was making dinner when Mum arrived (a completed action) . Past Perfect 7. When Mum came back from the park, Dad had already made dinner.

@Adam: I wish you would stop "misquoting" people. What I see Kate wrote is When I was in my twenties I was working long hours. To me that's a "plausible" utterance, even though normally, I'd expect Simple Past ...I worked long hours. But you seem to have transposed that into When I was a kid I was going to school every day, which I don't naturally find plausible. With your far lower level of fluency, you shouldn't even consider using any of these more "exotic" combinations of verb tenses. Competent native speakers may sometimes "push the boundaries", but you shouldn't!

Adam, it's difficult to explain how a native speaker instinctively decides whether or not to use a continuous tense. We wouldn't use it for normal, routine activities ('I went to school every day', 'I worked long hours') but we can use it for ongoing activities that were limited to a certain period of time. 'At that time I was attending Newtown School'. 'When I was in my twenties I was working long hours, but once I had established my career I had more free time'.


The teakettle was whistling on the stove.
She was working a full day six days a week and a half day on Sundays, and still the partners at the law firm felt she wasn't pulling her weight in terms of billable hours, so she quit.

Those are both idiomatic English sentences. Maybe the law example isn't the same in England, but otherwise the sentence should fly on either side of the Atlantic.
Do you see a temporal difference between "was whistling" and "was working"? Should we call them both "past ongoing actions"?
The whistling is uninterrupted.  The working is repetitive, day after day.
Suppose you're at a job interview. The interviewer asks:

What did you do immediately after school?

and you reply

I took a trip to New Zealand and worked as a waiter for a year to improve my English skills.

And then the interviewer says

I see that you took a job after that at the North Pole, as a customer service representative for Santa Enterprises, and stayed there for two years. But there's a gap of three years between that job and your next one. What were you doing during those three years?

And you reply

I was serving time for theft of trade secrets.  I broke into R&D and took pictures of some of Santa's sleigh designs and sold them to a company that makes rockets.


What I'd like to explain is this. "Last year I was driving a truck". Even though it was repeated day after day we use continuous and I'm fine with that in my mother tongue I'd use the continuois version too. What I don't understand is why for instance "When I was little I was going to school"(meaning regular occurance) is not fine anymore. It's something repeated so how is it different to my first example with driving?

Where did you find that "When I was little I was going to school" sentence? Have you reproduced it in its entirety?

I made it up on my own

Love the examples :))) “Santa Enterprises... I broke into R&D and took pictures of some of Santa's sleigh designs” snorts

That barebones sentence lacks context that would justify was going.

You need something to justify the continuous. All you've done is provided a context that shows you attended school like millions of other kids. It was your "occupation" and to express what our job was, we use simple past.  "I went to school when I was a kid, just like you."

@Adam are you Italian by any chance? The L'indicativo imperfetto  "quando ero piccolo andavo a scuola" is not "When I was small I was going to school" Instead in English it's "When I was a child I went to (or) I used to go to school"

@TimR. What justifies continuous here? 1 "Before I retired, I was working long hours at two jobs." 2 "Last year I was driving a truck".

Polish .mmmmmmm

The "long hours at two jobs" establishes the context of a tiring work schedule, and the continuous is compatible with that context and contributes to it. As you say near the top of your question, "to emphasize length".

If we place "last year I was driving a truck" in the proper context, one which focuses on the activity of driving itself, as distinct from the occupation of truck-driver, the continuous can be justified there as well.  These tenses are compatible with contexts, and contribute to contexts, but they don't really have the power, on their own, to create the context.

"Last year I was driving a truck, one of those trucks that have two, sometimes three, trailers attached to the cab, and the trailers started fishtailing and I lost control."

"When I was a kid, on any given Saturday I could | would | might be mowing lawns to earn extra money." How is it justified here?

Btw thank you very much

Similar to the truck-driving example, the focus on the activity itself, not on the "occupation". With the continuous, the lawn-mowing is not cast as an occupation but as something you might have found me doing to earn extra on any given Saturday. That sentence could fit into a context where the story is about the variety of things a person did as a kid to earn money.  And during the week, I might be hanging old Mrs Smith's laundry up on the clothesline for her, or taking our other elderly neighbor's trash cans out to the curb on trash day.

The past continuous is more compatible with  a vignette -style recollection than the simple past is.  might have been taking...

Here's the secret to the past continuous. There is usually a "when" or "while" either explicitly or implied when using it or a relationship to a present continuous.

I see you are working now. What were you doing last year?

Last year at this time [the when idea], I was driving a truck.

As an adult, I was working [implied when] then kicked the bucket and am now in heaven.

I told you not to go into the walk-in freezer. Whatever were you doing in there? [while or when you are in there].

When I was in Paris, I was working. Now, I'm not.


